# A way to have comment box as pop up, everywhere in shop?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, popup

Is there a way, to have a comment box (for customers), always available, where they can add comments for their order, instead of having a static comment box at the checkout, product or cart page?

I prefer to have a little 'chat' a-like pop-up, available after clicking the 'comment' link, floating right at the screen. Here the customer can fill in their comments any time, and will be saved automatic to the order they will place.

Hope you can help?

Comment: Is it not more related to general comments and suggestions about your website rather than comments regarding the order?

Comment: No it has to be send with the order. Customers want to enter some missing products, or special remarks.

Comment: I understand, but why would they do that everywhere on the site and not at the end of the order?

Comment: I don't think why is relevant to my question if this is possible and how it can be managed.